# "XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor" error, contrary do Mozilla docs on usage inside browser chrome

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I am building a Mozilla AddOn, using the AddOn SDK. I need to make an AJAX post, so I'm using `XMLHttpRequest`. In [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) it says that `XMLHttpRequest`

> can't be instantiated using the XMLHttpRequest() constructor. The constructor is not defined inside components and the code results in an error. The best way to work around this is to use the XPCOM component constructor.

The docs say to do it this way:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = Components.Constructor["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"];
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Fine. So  I implement the code exactly as it's shown in the docs:

```
var { Cc, Cu, Ci, Cr, Cm, components } = require('chrome');
const XMLHttpRequest = components.Constructor["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"];
. . .
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

And I get a "*XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor*" error on this line.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong here? I can't use the "`Components.Constructor["@...`" way because the AddOn SDK CLI tool that generates the `.xpi` file complains, saying that

> use 'Components' to access chrome authority. To do so, you need to add a line somewhat like the following:
>
> `const {components} = require("chrome");`
>
> Then you can use any shortcuts to its properties that you import from the 'chrome' module ('Cc', 'Ci', 'Cm', 'Cr', and 'Cu' for the 'classes', 'interfaces', 'manager', 'results', and 'utils' properties, respectively. And `components` for `Components` object itself).

OK, fine. I do have the `require(chrome)` call at the top of my file, and generate the shortcuts, and then amusing `components`, which is the correct form, and which the message from the AddOn compiler says to use. And yet I get the error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [`request` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html) in the Add-on SDK.

Should you for some reason still want to use `nsIXMLHttpRequest` directly, please note that the correct way to produce the constructor in an SDK module would be:

```js
XMLHttpRequest = components.Constructor(
  "@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1",
  "nsIXMLHttpRequest");
```

Except that `components.Constructor()` doesn't seem to work in the SDK. So better create an instance directly:

```js
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
var r = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].
        createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
r.open("GET", "http://example.org/");
r.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
    console.log(this, e, e.type, this.responseText);
});
r.send();
```

The MDN wiki(!) information is simply incorrect. I edited the article now and set the "Technical Review needed" flag.

Comment: Thank you, @nmaier - much appreciate the help. I'll try both the `request` and your edited XMLHttpRequest edits. I'd forgotten about `request` - probably the easiest approach. Thank you again~

Comment: Hello again, nmaier: Another question for you: Assuming I use the `nsIXMLHttpRequest` form, as you show above (which seems to work fine), when you do a POST, what is the name under which what you're sending is called? I ask because at the server end, where I deal with the POST, i can't get at the contents of what was POSTed; I'm using Node.js, and you extract the contents of a POST through `request.body`, which can have keys with values. But in my case nothing appears to be being sent. I'm sending a (URI encoded) string; should i be sending an object made up of a key and value instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or:

```
const { XMLHttpRequest } = require('sdk/net/xhr');

let r = new XMLHttpRequest();

console.dir(r);
r.open("GET", "http://example.org/");
r.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
    console.log(this, e, e.type, this.responseText);
});
r.send();
```

See [these docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/net/xhr.html) for more info and limitations.

Comment: Thank you, canuckistani. I think with all the limitations and the unstable designation for this approach, using `request` is probably the better bet. But, this is a valid suggestion, and I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I imported it like this:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

But I used Node.js...